# One word not followed by a series of other words including itself

Tags: javascript, regex

Say you have

```
catdogbird
```

I want to know when dog is present and not followed by, say, bird or dog or nothing at all.

I tried using a negative lookahead

```
dog(?!bird|dog)

catlizard    no match OK
catdogbird   no match OK
catdoglizard match OK
catdog       match OOPS
catdogdog    match OOPS
```

I don't want these last two matches, i.e. dog not followed by anything or dog followed by itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$` matches the end of a string in regex:

```
dog(?!bird|dog|$)
```

Will fix both the errors above (The second error was because the second "dog" followed by the end of the string was matching).

Comment: `catdogdoglizard` would still match the regex, when it shouldn't according to the question.

Comment: @Kolink Why shouldn't that match? It has "dog" followed by something other than "bird" and "dog".

Answer (score 0):

Require that it matches something after 'dog':

```
/dog(?!bird|dog).+$/
```